Can this oscillator possibly work?
I am trying to build a crude RF oscillator.  My first attempt, though it simulated fine, disappointingly did not oscillate when soldered together.  So, to debug this, I reduced the simulation example to this simple diode-connected circuit which still oscillates:


I would bet the oscillations shown above (near the NPN's datasheet cutoff frequency of 300 MHz) are not real, but I did not build this simple circuit for proof.  This might be an LTspice simulator bug (but the waveforms do not show any glaring problems on close inspection: voltages are shown with green base, red collector, and blue emitter) or simply an "NPN model bug/challenge".
For the record, I have tried all reasonable parasitics that I can think of, but stripped them out to keep the simulation example above simple.  In the end, the only physically-possible change that stops these oscillations is adding 10\$\Omega\$ to the collector and 5\$\Omega\$ to the emitter, which might be reasonable given the 300 MHz skin depth of about 3um.  But, that leaves me thinking that this simple NPN oscillator is possible if wider metal had been used inside the NPN package.
Is that really possible?  Is there any known NPN which will oscillate in simple diode-connected mode (with tight wire inductances and the intentional supply inductance as shown in the schematic above)?  I know RF has many strange effects, so I am a little hopeful.
By the way, I am also able to stop the oscillations by adding parallel resistance to the wire inductance, but I don't consider that to be physical...I still have doubts about this, but will leave that for a second Stack Exchange question (to post later today).
